# Jquery .After get code from div html

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$(".mydivclass").after('<div>something here</div>');
```

What I'd like to do is to get the code to be injected from a div elsewhere.

So where you see: `<div>something here</div>` above I need to add the code from some other place for example:

```
$(".mydivclass").after(get div id="block1");

<div id="block1">add this above</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to move the block1 div or copy it?

Comment: what do you plan to do with duplicate ID's? Or do you just want what's inside the other element?

Answer (score 1):

Simply clone the div to create a copy (and remove `id`).

```
$(".mydivclass").after($("#block1").clone().removeAttr('id'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jgnrmupc/

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = $("#block1").html();

$(".myBlockClass").html(html);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jykd6j4p/

Comment: What you did was replace the existing content with the content of the block.  The original question asked to add a copy of the block after the existing content.

Comment: True. I misread the question as wanting the content of the div, not the whole div. I assumed the OP could extrapolate from the example. Your solution is complete.